# Удержать socket открытым с клиентской части

Tags: java, android, сокет

Есть вот такой код клиентской части:

```
Socket remoteServer;
remoteServer = new Socket("192.168.0.55",4445);

BufferedReader in  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(remoteServer.getInputStream()));
PrintWriter    out = new  PrintWriter(remoteServer.getOutputStream(),true);
BufferedReader ios = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

String fromClient,fromserver;

while ((fromClient = ios.readLine())!=null)
{
  out.println(fromClient);
  //out.write(fromClient);
  fromserver = in.readLine();
  System.out.println(fromserver);
  if (fromClient.equalsIgnoreCase("close")) break;

}

out.close();
in.close();
ios.close();
remoteServer.close();
```

Т.е подключается к серверу и держит открытым соединение за счёт цикла, пока не придет "close". Но тут также держит и за счёт System.in, т.к данные получает с консоли. Но вот надо переделать под Андроид и проблема в том, что надо текст получать из editText, и вот на этом моменте застрял.

Если сделать вот так:

```
String fromClient = "Text",fromserver;

  out.println(fromClient);
  //out.write(fromClient);
  fromserver = in.readLine();
  System.out.println(fromserver);
  //if (fromClient.equalsIgnoreCase("close")) break;
```

То вроде как и работает, НО, соединение естественно после отправки закрывается, т.к нету цикла который бы держал открытым соединение. В общем как сделать что-бы по аналогии с первым куском кода, держалось открытым до получения "close"? Спасибо.

Comment: код чтения-записи для сокета перенести в отдельный поток.

Comment: Вынесено с самого начала. По другому не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Когда я делал Socket-соединение, то всю работу сокета я перенес в `Service`, в котором чтение-запись были в отдельном потоке. Думаю, что это наиболее подходящий вариант.

Comment: В AciveSync вынесено. Первый кусок кода работает с удержанием. Дело не в потоках, а в цикле.

Comment: А что не так с циклом? Я в отдельном потоке запускал цикл while, который выполнялся до тех пор, пока не было команды закрыть соединение.

Comment: Так вот в этом и вопрос. Как этот цикл сделать, по аналогии с первым кодом. Без использования System.in